# How to send click_action Firebase notification. (SWIFT)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

This is the code I have to send a message. The message gets sent just fine and my phone receives the remote notification; however, the notification is not an actionable notification as I need it be.

Please Help! I need any suggestions or help in Swift.

I am trying to send an upstream message. I want this message to be an actionable notification on the receiving device.

```
 "notification": [
    "body" : "\(emergencyMessage.text!)",
    "title" : "EMERGENCY!",
    "sound" : "alert.aiff", // or specify audio name to play

        ],
    "apns":[
    "payload": [
    "aps": [
        "category": "GENERAL"
        ]
        ]
        ]



        ]


        as [String : Any]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`click_action` is not a payload option on APNs. I believe the key you're looking for is `category`. See [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CreatingtheNotificationPayload.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH10-SW1) for details on what options exist for the APNs payload.

If you're using the [console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/notification) to send notifications, that should be enough to get you started. If you're using a server, keep reading.

When using platform-specific overrides--like keys that exist only on iOS and not Android--make sure you are using [FCM v1](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server#implementing-the-http-server-protocol) and that you're using the [right notation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#when_to_use_common_keys). For example, to set up the category `GENERAL` would look like this:

```
 "apns": {
   "payload": {
     "aps": {
       "category": "GENERAL"
     }
   }
 },
```

Comment: Jen, Thank you so much for the insights! It is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is what I have now, this is the code from the device that I am initiating the message from. My phone is still receiving the notification, but it still isn't actionable . Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: "notification": [
        "body" : "\(emergencyMessage.text!)",
        "title" : "EMERGENCY!",
        "sound" : "alert.aiff", // or specify audio name to play
                
            ],
        "apns":[
        "payload": [
        "aps": [
            "category": "GENERAL"
            ]
            ]
            ]
    
    
    
            ]
            
           
            as [String : Any]

Comment: Instead of writing as a comment, update your question to include this change. There isn't enough information in your question to determine what's causing the problem. Include how you are sending the message: from a server using FCM v1, from the client using XMPP, or from the console. Include the code you're using to handle the category once it's received. Judging from the format of this comment, you're trying to send the message from the client. The code I shared is for sending from a *server*

Comment: Is it possible to send actionable notifications using the upstream message function?

Comment: No, but unless you're sending an "acknowledge" type message, there's no compelling reason to use the upstream functionality over a server. I would use a server with the Firebase Admin SDK for FCM.

Comment: Can I use a server and still be able to send the notification message from my iPad to my iPhone? Which server do you recommend?